# What does "You'll never get this tart to your dessert plate" mean in this quote?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Caller: I met this beautiful woman.
>
> Anchor: Ugh. Come on, Ed. If you start telling me you're in love
>   again,I'm gonna remind you of that time we made you propose to that
>   checkout girl at Thrifty's. Do you remember her reaction?
>
> Caller: She was just a girl. This is a beautiful woman.
>
> Anchor: And **Pinocchio is a true story. You'll never get this tart to
>   your dessert plate**.

When I googled **Pinocchio** it shows me cartoon pictures.

**Tart** is informal word which is about a girl, so what does it means by "**tart to your dessert plate**" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [tart](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tart) is also a dessert.

> You'll never get this tart to your dessert plate.

This means that you will never enjoy this delicacy. To rephrase: you will never enjoy the intimate company of this woman.

Stating that Pinocchio is a true story is a way of stating that not everything you hear is truth.

Comment: And what has this to do with the context?

Comment: It means the person will never enjoy the intimate company of this woman.

Comment: @Clare it's a pun on the dual meaning of "tart".  A tart is a kind of dessert, but it's also slang for a woman.  To "get onto your dessert plate" means, metaphorically, to have a relationship with, or just to have sex with.  A similar (slightly more crude) expression would be "you'll never get that bird to land on your branch", where "bird" is another slang term for a female, and "branch" should be self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

"get {x} to {a place}"  =  succeed in bringing or taking {x} to {the place}.

> Can we get him to the train station on time?
>
> With two broken arms, I could not get the spoon to my mouth.

Davo has explained the "tart" pun.  But you should be aware that when applied to a girl or a woman, the word *tart* is pejorative and disrespectful, at least in American English. It is not simply "informal". A tart is a dessert, or a woman who is often, though not always, of a lower economic class than the speaker, and is of little importance to the speaker; a "tart" is easily discarded and disregarded.

The story of Pinocchio is a fantasy about a wooden puppet whose nose grows long whenever he tells a lie. He turns into a real flesh-and-blood boy.

Comment: FYI, this quote is from **[The Fisher King](https://books.google.com/books?id=aYvFAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA201&lpg=PA201&dq=You%27ll+never+get+this+tart+to+your+dessert+plate&source=bl&ots=9Ev3h4LDLQ&sig=DOyXtk2L7Y4aH3dv93oz1nV5x5U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOn_Lc8fHTAhWC6iYKHab5AwYQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=You'll%20never%20get%20this%20tart%20to%20your%20dessert%20plate&f=false)**. Stating that Pinocchio is a true story, he is implying that one should not believe everything that one hears.

Comment: I agree that "tart" can be a *slightly* derogatory term for a sexually suggestive female, but nowadays there are so many worse terms used casually that "tart" seems old-fashioned and quaint.   Also, at least in BrE, "get tarted up" means to put on makeup and a provocative outfit, and generally make yourself look sexually attractive, and is more fun and even *empowering* than derogatory.

Comment: There's a big difference between calling a woman "a tart" and the phrase "get tarted up". But my point to the OP is that it isn't a synonym for other informal words, such as "chick", but a derogatory term. Where on the derogatory scale it falls is a matter of opinion —you may have to ask a woman you just called a "tart" to find out.